# Cannot link to existing libopenblas.so.0 DLL

Tags: c++, linux, dll, shared-libraries

I need to use the [libpca](https://github.com/spinlockirqsave/libpca-1.2.11) in C++, which depends on [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html), which in turn requires [OpenBlas](https://www.openblas.net/) and [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/#_lapack_version_3_8_0_2).

I got some problems in installing/configuring these dependencies.

I am using Red Hat 4.8.5-16 and wish to write code and call the package in `/my/dir/program/`. I do NOT have sudo privilege.

All those packages are downloaded and unzipped in `/my/dir/`

Here is the steps I have followed:

```
1. to install OpenBlas
    /my/dir/OpenBLAS-0.2.20$  make
    /my/dir/OpenBLAS-0.2.20$  make PREFIX=/my/dir/program/
    <Step 1 is successful>

2. to install lapack
    /my/dir/lapack-3.8.0$ mv make.inc.example make.inc
    /my/dir/lapack-3.8.0$ make
    <Step 2 is successful>

3. to install Armadillo
    /my/dir/armadillo-8.500.0$ cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/my/dir/pgrogram/
    /my/dir/armadillo-8.500.0$ make
    /my/dir/armadillo-8.500.0$ make install
    <Step 3 is successful>

4. to compile the example code
    /my/dir/armadillo-8.500.0$ cp examples/example1.cpp /my/dir/program
    /my/dir/program$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/:../OpenBLAS-0.2.20/:../armadillo-8.500.0/:./lib/:./lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ;
    /my/dir/program$ g++ example1.cpp -o example1 -O2 -I./include -L./lib -L./lib64 -L../lapack-3.8.0 -L../OpenBLAS-0.2.20 -larmadillo -lopenblas -llapack  ;
    <There is no warning or error in compiling>

5. to run the example code
    /my/dir/program$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/:../OpenBLAS-0.2.20/:../armadillo-8.500.0/:./lib/:./lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ;
    /my/dir/program$ ./example1
```

It returns

> ./example1: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Actually the `libopenblas.so.0` dll is located in `./lib/`, and I've already added the DLL path.

Since I do not have root privilege, I cannot `yum install openblas.x86_64 openblas-devel.x86_64` as suggested by [this](https://github.com/sermanet/OverFeat/issues/10) post.

What should I do?

Comment: For g++ to find `libmkl_rt.so` is one thing. ... Running `./example1` is a new situation : The location information must be repeated : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel.. .. ...:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && ./example1`

Comment: I modified the command and the original errors went away. Now it reports `libopenblas.so.0`, which is actually located in `./lib`, cannot be found (see the updated description). I've added that path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running `./example1`, but the error is still there. How to solve this problem?

Comment: See my previous comment : The "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel... " ends with ":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" . I.e. means you also include all the system LD_LIBRARY_PATH´s .

Comment: It works, thank you!  Your first reply actuall works. I used `export` in a shell file and `bash`-ed it. then excuted `./example1` which leads to the error. It turns out that the `export` and the execution should be in the same shell. Please paste your solution as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For g++ / ld to find `libmkl_rt.so` is one thing.

Running `./example1` is a new situation : The "location information" must be repeated →

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel.. .. ...:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && ./example1
```

Please be aware that the **export** command is temporary : Valid for the current shell session only. When you exit the shell, the command is cancelled.